# Fractals and measuring a piece of paper

Tags: fractals

Traditionally, I was taught that a piece of paper was 2d, so I decided to measure it, as if it was a square, since for a square, the area is just the length of one side squared. So for an 8.5 by 11 inch sheet of paper, the area would be 93.5 in^2. What I'm confused about right now is how 11 raised to the (log base 11 of (8.5)) plus one is 1.89, which is less than 2d, while 8.5 raised to the (log base 8.5 of (11)) plus one is greater than 2. I feel as though there is a correct way to do this, and I'm doing something wrong here. Thanks ! [image: Here is my work]

Comment: Please use MathJax. You can find out how here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're using a different model of fractal dimension, but the one I'm familiar with has to do with *scaling*, not size. If you scale the piece of paper by a factor of $n$, you scale the, say, measure of the paper by a factor of $n^2$ since $A'=(nb)(nh)=n^2A$. In general, we say an object has dimension $D$ if scaling the object by a factor of $n$ results in scaling the (what we're calling) measure by a factor of $n^D$. Thus, in the case of the paper, we get $D=2$.

Comment: ok...I think I'm starting to understand. so, is the reason paper is considered 2D because the way we "measure" it is by using the formula A= b * h ? It's just hard to intuit what is going on. Say I folded the paper in half - what would be going on there ? From what I understand, the dimension should decrease, but I don't see why. The more iterations of folding the paper would make it smaller... so what I'm essentially asking is how we measure dimension. I've tried using a box counting program, but my results were off, and I want to understand why.  Basically, I'm asking what the real world mea

Comment: What the real world meaning of n is. sorry it got cut off ! Also, I should say I'm not sure what would happen if you folded the paper - I meant moreso if you halved the paper. My intuition says dimension would decrease, but this is non-euclidean geomotry, so I'm out of my comfort zone. Thanks !

Comment: If by halve the paper you just mean cutting it in half, then you would just have half as much paper; nothing would change. If by halving it you mean scaling it by 1/2, i.e. reducing all distances between points of the square by a factor of 1/2, then 1/2=n and you end up with a piece of paper that's 1/4, or (1/2)^2, as large. Scaling does not affect dimension, since after it's scaled, scaling still affects the object the same.

Comment: You can also think of scaling by n as measuring distances with units that are 1/n as large as the original units, rather than actually changing the size of the paper. So if you measure in inches, you get A=93.5, but if you measure in feet you'll get A=93.5(1/12)^2

Comment: And yes, the dimension is determined by the fact that measure is equivalent to the product of two lengths.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense, thanks. For measuring dimension, we measure our n (scaling factor) against the boxes counted to get our dimension, right ?

Comment: Right. To be more precise, n is the ratio of number of boxes counted along a distance after scaling to before.

Answer (score 1):

One way of characterizing the dimension of an object is the *similarity dimension*.  Roughly speaking, we ask "If we scale our set down by some fixed factor, how many copies of the scaled set are needed to reconstruct the original set?"  Note that this does assume that a set can be made out of scaled copies of itself, i.e. that the set is *self-similar*.  We also probably need to assume some separation properties, but that is maybe beyond the scope of this answer---again, we are speaking very roughly.

For example:

1. A line segment of length 1.  If we scale the segment by a factor of $C<1$, we get a segment of length $C$.  In general, we will need $N = \frac{1}{C}$ copies of the scaled segment to reconstruct the original.  As a particular case, suppose that $C = \frac{1}{4}$.  Then, after scaling, it would take four copies of a segment of length $\frac{1}{4}$ to get the original interval back again.  In this case, note that
   $$ N = \frac{1}{C}.$$
2. A square with side length 1.  If we scale the square down by a factor of $C<1$, we end up with a square of side length $C$.  Such a square has an area of $C^2$, and the original square had an area of 1, so it will generally take $N = \frac{1}{C^2}$ copies of the scaled square to rebuild the original.  Again, as a particular case, note that it will take $16$ squares of side length $\frac{1}{4}$ to recover the original square.  Hence
   $$ N = \frac{1}{C^2}. $$
3. A cube of side length 1.  In this case, it takes $C^3$ scaled cubes to get the original cube (e.g. consider a Rubik's cube, which is made up of 27 cubes, each of which has $\frac{1}{3}$ the side length of the entire Rubik's cube).  Here
   $$ N = \frac{1}{C^3}. $$

While this isn't entirely rigorous, we might note the following pattern:
\begin{array}{llll}
\textbf{Shape:} & \textbf{Dimension:} & \textbf{Copies vs Scaling:} & \textbf{Exponent:} \\
\text{segment} & \text{one} & N = \frac{1}{C} & 1 \\
\text{square} & \text{two} & N = \frac{1}{C^2} & 2 \\
\text{cube} & \text{three} & N = \frac{1}{C^3} & 3 \\
\end{array}
What we might notice is that an $s$-dimensional object can be reconstructed $\frac{1}{C^s}$ copies of itself, each of which has been scaled by a factor of $C$.  Thus the dimension of an object is the solution $s$ to the equation
$$ N = \frac{1}{C^s}. $$
Solving, we get
$$ N = \frac{1}{C^s}
\implies \log(N) = -s\log(C)
\implies s = -\frac{\log(N)}{\log(C)}.$$
Thus the dimension is obtained by comparing the logarithms of the number of copies and the scaling ratio.  Note that $s$ will be positive, since $N$ is (typically) an integer (and will be greater than 1 in any event), and $C$ was assumed to be less than 1 (so that $\log(C) < 0$).

In the case of an $8.5\times 11$ inch piece of paper, if you scale it down by a factor of $C = \frac{1}{2}$, you end up with a piece of paper that is $4.25\times 5.5$ inches.  We can tape/staple/glue $N=4$ such pieces of paper together in order to recover the original piece of paper, thus
$$\dim(\text{piece o' paper})
= -\frac{\log(4)}{\log(\frac{1}{2})}
= -\frac{\log(2^2)}{\log(2^{-1})}
= -\frac{2\log(2)}{-\log(2))}
= 2.$$
This implies that a piece of paper is two-dimensional, which is the expected result.

---

themathandlanguagetutor's answer gives a very slightly (and subtly) different notion of dimension, called the Minkowski dimension.  Instead of comparing the number of copies of a set needed to rebuild the set to the scaling ratio, the Minkowski dimension compares the *measure* (length, or area, or volume, etc.) of a set to the scaling ratio.  In nice cases, these two ideas agree, which is gratifying!